# Drools and Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, drools

I am trying to create a WebSerivce inside a default project given by the JBOSS plugin for ECLIPSE. I tried to create an endpoint based on this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

the problem is that once i declare my methods and i run the .publish() i get an error:
[MY publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSZ4z.jpg)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;

does anyone have an ideia what it might be?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Sorry, did it now, thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code to Stack Overflow. Links to external sites change and the usefulness of the question is lost over time.

Answer (score 0):

Well in case someone gets this problem, I exported as a Jar the drools project and the webservice runs this project externally.